# Django Collectstatic in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Not Working

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-staticfiles

I have deployed my Django app in amazon elastic beanstalk. However, the css in the django admin is not working. I understand that it's a collectstatic issue. This is what my **settings.py** looks like:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And I have this line in my **ebconfig.config** file:

```
container_commands:
  01_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

However, this is how it looks like once I deploy it in amazon:
[image]
I have tried seeing the log files in amazon console. I found a line that reads:

```
EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_dcape/Command 01_collectstatic] : Starting activity...
.....  
  0 static files copied to '/opt/python/bundle/33/app/static', 102 unmodified.
```

What do I need to do to make sure it works?

Comment: i also don't know how to make the image smaller. any help?

Comment: Seems collectstatic already copied necessary files I think without admin. Now can you describe your folder structure

Comment: Why do you call `os.path.dirname` two times ?

Comment: I have the same problem here. CSS in my main app works fine, however all the paths to the admin's static show 404 on the live server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk not serving django static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043073/amazon-elastic-beanstalk-not-serving-django-static-files)

Comment: Do you have a variable `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue for the longest time. It seems like you have to tell beanstalk where your static folder will be located on the production server.

In your **ebconfig.config** where you specify commands/container_commands add an option settings so that beanstalk can know what your static_root equates to on the live server.

This is how I do it:

*settings.py*

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

*config file*

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: MDGOnline.settings
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "static/": "www/static/"
```

Check out this wonderful [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html) for more detailed info