# Deploy Django with TailwindCSS on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tailwind-css

Good day,

I recently deployed a Django project to Elastic Beanstalk using the following tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-elastic-beanstalk/

This is the website: http://gmoonline4-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

The website works fine, including the admin and database, except for the CSS, which gives an error

This template loads properly in development, but you can see the end product after deployment.

I tried including the container_command "python3 manage.py tailwind start", but this fails the deployment.

Can anyone assist me with this? I am not sure if this is an error in my django application or my EB configuration.

Thanks! If you need any code, I'll post it here

Comment: What does your static file setting looks like? Did you check this document? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html.  Also you need to give us an output of the container command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043073/amazon-elastic-beanstalk-not-serving-django-static-files check this answer if it helps